# ModSecurity: Output filter: Failed to read bucket (rc 104): Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, django, apache, rest, mod-security

I'm doing a POST request to a rest service made with django and piston uploading a file, but when I do the request i get this (strange?) error:

```
[Sun Jul 04 16:12:38 2010] [error] [client 79.39.191.166] ModSecurity: Output filter: Failed to read bucket (rc 104): Connection reset by peer [hostname "url"] [uri "/api/odl/"] [unique_id "TDEVZEPNBIMAAGLwU9AAAAAG"]
```

What does it mean? And how can I debug it?

Comment: Figured out anything in the last few months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Output filtering](http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/1.9.3/html-multipage/04-rules.html) is a way for an administrator to check all text that go through Apache for a specific set a strings, and then block those requests.

You have two options:

1. Look at the mod_security filter rules inside your apache config.
2. Remove half of your text from your output, and see if it works or not. If it did, the problem string is inside that block of text. Repeat with smaller and smaller chunks of text until you have found the offending string.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to implement CRSF protection as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax